# Looking for English Texts for testing user possible input

Tags: testing, iso-8859-1, manual-testing

Looking for English Texts for testing user possible input (with all special characters and different combination for testing proper encode end decode of user input  of my website.
my website have ISO-8859-1 and not utf-8)

thanks,
Yosef

Comment: Why are you not using UTF-8? See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893946/iso-8859-1-vs-utf-8

Comment: because this old website that somebody else decide about encoding

Answer (score 1):

Hum... Both Wikipedia and Stack Overflow publish dumps with all their content periodically. This text is common English however, and it will only contain special chars as they appear in ordinary text.

Comment: Thanks, I need something smaller, max 2000 chars - I doing it manually